# C# webrequest returning Json value, outputing amount of the results using Random

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, random, httpwebrequest

I am working on a little exercise for fun using the Cat Facts api. 
The problem I am running into, is not by displaying a random 'cat fact' one at a time. But i am trying to display a random amount of facts up to five total. For example, user clicks the button gets 3 facts, user clicks the button again and gets 1 fact, user clicks the button a third time and either gets 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5  facts. Im attempting to do everything in one activity/class. http://catfacts-api.appspot.com/api/facts?number=5 will display 5 facts and http://catfacts-api.appspot.com/api/facts will return one.
This is how my code looks thus far,

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
private ImageButton _mrWhiskersButton;
private TextView _catFactsTextView;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        _mrWhiskersButton = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.imageCatButton);
        _catFactsTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.catFactsText);

        _mrWhiskersButton.Click += async delegate
        {


            string url = "Http://catfacts-api.appspot.com/api/facts";
            JsonValue json = await FetchInfoAsync(url);
            updateCats(json);
        };

    }
    public async Task<JsonValue> FetchInfoAsync(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";

        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonValue.Load(stream));
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Response: {0}", jsonDoc.ToString());
                return jsonDoc;
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateCats(JsonValue json)
    {

        _catFactsTextView.Text = json["facts"][0];
    }

}
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what exactly isn't working, or what it's supposed to be doing that it isn't.  Please re-read what you posted to be sure that you're stating the problem clearly.

Comment: so if you click the link http://catfacts-api.appspot.com/api/facts?number=5   you will see that it generates 5 random facts. now mine currently only displays 1. I believe i have to do something like Random random = new Random(); Because i want to be able to click the imageButton to get a random fact, and that also being a random number of facts, up to a max of 5 facts displayed. I hope this clears up the confusion.

Comment: you are calling "/api/facts" - you are not including "?number=5" or any other argument after "facts".  Even if it were returning multiple facts, your updateCats() method only displays the first one.

Comment: Could i do a if else statement within the updateCats method, that uses a random int. to determine what line will be outputted? for example:    Random num = new Random();    if(num == 5) { _catFactsTextView.Text = json["facts"][5]; }   else if (num == 4) { _catFactsTextView.Text = json["facts"][4];}  so on. ?

Comment: you're making it more complex than it needs to be - see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
  private ImageButton _mrWhiskersButton;
  private TextView _catFactsTextView;
  private System.Random rand;

  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
  {
    base.OnCreate(bundle)

    rand = new System.Random();

    // omitted code...

    _mrWhiskersButton.Click += async delegate
    {
        // get next random int between 1 and 5
        int ndx = rand.Next(1,5);
        string url = $"Http://catfacts-api.appspot.com/api/facts?number={ndx}";
        JsonValue json = await FetchInfoAsync(url);
        updateCats(json);
    };

}
  private void updateCats(JsonValue json)
  {
      foreach (var fact in json["facts"]) {
        _catFactsTextView.Text += fact + "\n";          
      }

  }
```

Comment: I understand what your suggesting. However it still only displays one fact. There is a error int the string url in your response. There is not bracket between facts (and) ?number=5. So what I'm attempting to do is append the url with a random number out of 5.

Comment: do you want to request a random number of facts and then display ALL of the requested facts?  If so, see my edited answer.

Comment: trying to get a random selection of any of these result options when a button is clicked { http://catfacts-api.appspot.com/api/facts?number=1  OR   http://catfacts-api.appspot.com/api/facts?number=2  OR http://catfacts-api.appspot.com/api/facts?number=3 OR 4/5 }  and I thought the same thing about  {ndx} and changing the number based on the random selection. It doesnt seem to be displaying more than one at a time. I believe it could have to do with the url being a string, i would have to convert the random number to a string for it to work in the position of ndx?

Comment: That has nothing to do with it.  You need to use the debugger to step through you code and verify that it's returning the correct data, deserializing it to json, and then iterating through the results to print them.  Don't guess what the problem is - you need to methodically track it down.

Comment: Apologize. You are completely correct. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out with this situation. I'm sure you will be responding to some future Xamarin questions of mine =) ty for taking the time helping us out that are learning Xamarin and c#.